# Why does azure storage explorer keep crashing?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

My problem is: every time i open Azure Storage Explorer, 10 seconds goes by and then the it crashes(closes). No error code, no nothing, just closes and that is it?
Does anyone know what is happening?

Regards.

Comment: You may be better off asking this question here - https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick check please follow the steps below,

1. Try to install the latest version of [Azure Storage Explorer](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/releases),
   [image]

2.Also, do close all other apps running in your system that consume excess CPU and try it.

Comment: Hello, i have tried the latest version and a few versions before that. Getting the same result.

Answer (score -1):

When i start the program with flag --debug from PowerShell this seems to go away.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).